# Игнорируются запросы на удаление профилей?

Tags: поддержка, удаление-профиля

В общем-то после вчерашнего обсуждения ответа оставленного мной, решил я удалить профиль отсюда, и более никогда не приходить на сей сайт.

Также оставил заявку на удаление остальных профилей. Спустя 24 часа, как и было написано в оповещении, мои профили были удалены. Однако, как можно видеть, на русском сайте, по всей видимости, данные запросы игнорируются.

> Эта учётная запись запланирована на удаление 2 дня назад. Чтобы отменить удаление нажмите сюда.

А теперь хочу увидеть кардинальное объяснение этому факту.

---

**UPD**:

Что это еще за разработчики?

> Вы недавно запросили удаление вашего профиля. Из-за вашего количества голосов и/или вашей репутации это удаление требует окончательного утверждения разработчиком, до того как оно будет завершено. Будучи утверждённым, ваш профиль будет удалён незамедлительно - вам не нужно планировать удаление вашего профиля снова.

Comment: Думаю, что нужно немного подождать

Comment: А что за «вчерашнее обсуждение ответа»?

Comment: [Why wasn't my account deleted immediately after the timer expiring?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7979/545792)

Comment: Правильно я понимаю, что после [обсуждения чужого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1322142/1365) (по факту, вашего несогласия с чужим ответом, ака "в интернете кто-то не прав") вы решили удалиться с этого сайта?

Comment: Это мое решение, разве этого не должно быть достаточно?

Comment: @206435 меня не особо волнует ваше удаление с сайта (похоже, что мы не пересекались на сайте или почти не пересекались). Просто немного удивляет такой подход — из-за малейшего "несовершенства мира" удаляться. Я бы просто поставил минус, если считаю ответ неправильным, и забил на ситуацию, где я больше ничем не могу повлиять.

Comment: Прошло 2 дня...

Answer (score 4):

Упомянутая вами строка в оригинале [выглядит так](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/4088):

> You recently requested deletion of your profile. Due to your number of votes and/or your reputation, this deletion requires final approval from a developer before it is completed. Once approved, your profile will be deleted immediately - you do not need to schedule your profile for deletion again.

Если немного поискать об этом на MSE можно найти, например, этот вопрос [Provide explanation to high reputation users that deleting their accounts may take longer than 24 hours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302013/339911)

Из него следует, что удаление профиля участника, который оставил заметный след на сайте (по кол-ву отданных голосов, например), может потребовать большего времени, нежели упомянутые 24 часа. Всё дело в том, что за утверждение удаления в таком случае уже отвечают сотрудники компании, а не обычные модераторы, выбранные/назначенные из числа обычных участников. Сотрудники - люди на зарплате и у них обычно есть более важные/срочные дела, чем утверждение удаления профиля участника. А учитывая, что основная часть сети Stack Exchange англоязычная, то можно предположить, что ожидается участие русскоязычного сотрудника. Таких людей в компании существенно меньше, чем англоязычных. Поэтому можно просто смириться и ждать. Или не ждать. Всё равно же решили удалиться, так зачем тратить время на ожидание этого удаления? Просто займитесь своими делами. Может быть по подтверждению будет какое-то уведомление на почту, но я в этом не уверен.

Всё. Удалился.